# how to get specific key value from json file?

Tags: typescript

I want to get only a specific field data from the list of JSON

MyJSON

```
{
"data": [
    {"answer": "Yes","email": "aaaa.cpm","color": "Maroon"},
    {"answer": "No","email": "bbbb.cpm","color": "White"},
    {"answer": "Yes","email": "cccc.cpm","color": "Black"}
]}
```

service file

```
 getCarsSmall() {
    return this.http.get<any>('assets/data/cars-large.json').suscribe(d=>{
console.log(d)
})     
  }
```

I want to display the result like this

Output

```
 [{"email": "aaaa.cpm","color": "Maroon"},{"email": "bbbb.cpm","color": "White"},{"email": "cccc.cpm","color": "Black"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want email then you can use

```
console.log(d["data"][0]['email'])
```

to access the first email.

Similarly, you can use iterators/loops to access each email.

```
for (var _i = 0; _i < d["data"].length; _i++) {
   console.log(d["data"][_i]['email'])
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. without using for loop if I want to email and color means how can I do it